# MySQL grant select bug?

Tags: mysql

Estoy preparando un `schema` o `database` común que contiene tablas de uso común a lo largo de varios proyectos. Todos los usuarios de MySQL deben tener permiso para ejecutar SOLAMENTE `select` sobre esas tablas. Para eso hago:

```
drop database if exists common_schema;

CREATE DATABASE common_schema CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
grant select on common_schema.* to ""@"";
flush privileges;
use common_schema;

set foreign_key_checks = 0;

-- creación_de_tablas
-- inserts
-- foreign_keys

set foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Toda la operación se ejecuta con un script de bash que es el sgte:

```
cat *.sql  > sql_completo.sql1
mv sql_completo.sql1 sql_completo.sql
mysql -u root -p < sql_completo.sql
rm sql_completo.sql
```

Dicho script concatena todos los archivos SQL y lo carga en MySQL.
El problema está en que cualquier usuario puede insertar, modificar o eliminar registros de `common_schema`, lo cual no debería ser.

Estoy usando MySQL 5.6.51.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Qué versión de MySQL usas?

Comment: @Alfabravo  5.6.51 (lo añado a la pregunta)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré la forma de hacerlo.

A pesar de que los permisos deben ser definidos explícitamente, `grant select on common_schema.* to ''@'%';` le otorgaba todos los permisos a todos los usuarios.

Les recuerdo: la idea era un `schema` común con permiso de `select` (únicamente) a todos los usuarios habidos y por haber, sin sacrificar al root/admin.

Primero hay que revocar los permisos, y luego adjudicar los necesarios:

```
revoke all on common_schema.* from ''@'%';
grant select on common_schema.* to ''@'%';
```

De ésta manera se revocan todos los permisos que no deberían haber sido adjudicados pero lo fueron, y luego con el `grant` se adjudican los permisos necesarios.

Y así, amiguitos, podemos tener un schema común al que todos puedan consultar pero solo el root pueda modificar.

hasta la próxima!

Answer (score 2):

Dos cosas:

- El comando `flush privileges` [es innecesario](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privilege-changes.html) en versiones recientes de MySQL si haces las cosas correctamente. Es un legado de versiones 3.x cuando había que refrescar todo al modificar las tablas de metadata. Ahora, si haces un GRANT, los permisos toman efecto inmediatamente (si hicieras un INSERT a las tablas de permisos, ahí sí toca hacer el flush). Así pues, no hay ningún bug en el comando porque no estás haciendo nada nuevo al ejecutarlo.
- Para no lidiar con la configuración por defecto de una base de datos nueva (que [no tiene](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-database.html) la opción de definir un owner o algo similar), bien podrías añadir un `REVOKE ALL ON common_schema FROM 'usuario_pepito'@'%';` para restringir a un usuario. Luego le das el SELECT con GRANT. Sin flush.

Comment: Entiendo. Entonces, como hago el `revoke all` para todos los usuarios y a continuación el `grant select` para todos los usuarios?

Comment: @julio sí, yo lo haría así. De paso, garantizas que lo que ofreces vía GRANT es el conjunto mínimo necesario de permisos. Uno pensaría en hacer REVOKE ALL ON database FROM '%@%' pero corre uno el riesgo de dejar sin permisos incluso al admin, je. Habría que ver el alcance de eso (hacer la prueba) porque MySQL no es tan poderoso en esa gestión (sería lindo poder definir un usuario owner y eso... hasta allá no me llega el conocimiento de MySQL, pero no he visto que se pueda)

Comment: buen punto. He pensado lo mismo sobre los permisos del root/admin y los ownerships. Me resulta muy inflexible MySQL en ocasiones. Puede que por ignorancia. Con la info que me diste en tus anteriores comentarios, voy a hacer algunas pruebas con el par de pájaros `revoke` y `grant` y ver cómo afecta a los usuarios, incluído el root. Ahora, si cuando creamos una bbdd debemos explicitar los permisos, estoy entendiendo que `grant select`, `grant update`, etc, y `grant all` es lo mismo...

Comment: @julio GRANT ALL incluye delete, alter,.... cuidado! :)

Comment: si si, generalizaba por el hecho de que se deben definir explícitamente los permisos para una db recién creada y que un GRANT SELECT permita otras operaciones. Este asunto está mejor planteado en MySQL 5.7 u 8?

Comment: @julio parece que [en 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/revoke.html) [hay](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) roles y algunas opciones más.